# Writing variables to files if file doesn't contain variable

Tags: php, file-get-contents, strpos

I am not sure why this doesn't work:

```
<?PHP
$user = $_GET['user'];
$write = $user . "\n";
if(strpos(file_get_contents("recent.txt"),$write) !== false){
    file_put_contents('recent.txt', $write, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
?>
```

What I am doing is to get the search term from a form and write it to a file. The way the original code is set up, it is only possible (as of 2014) to have 14,530,014 entries.

When the form is submitted (or `?user=SomeUser` is added to the URL), nothing happens to `recent.txt`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried testing if file_get_contents even works?  you're doing a lot of work at once, have you made sure each piece itself is working first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write the info if it is not contained in the file, you need to change

```
strpos(file_get_contents("recent.txt"),$write) !== false
```

to

```
strpos(file_get_contents("recent.txt"),$write) === false
```

`!== false` means that the file contents *do* contain the user you were looking for.  It would return `false` if the string was not found.

Additionally, you may want to add a call to [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) to check if `$_GET['user']` is actually set.

And depending on how large you expect this file to get, using a database to do this may be a much better (more efficient) option.

Comment: That works. :) What I would like to do with this is to give search suggestions based off of the words in `recent.txt`. I would like the script to find a maximum of three words which are on `recent.txt` which have similar spellings, then to `echo` them as links.